# How to remove all nodes from a singly linked list in x86 assembly

Tags: assembly, linked-list, x86

Currently I am given a linked list with only a next pointer but not a prev pointer. For walking down the list, it is relatively easy.

```
    movl NEXT(%ebx), %ebx # ebx is the current node
```

However, when trying to delete the list one by one from the end, I cannot seem to be able to formulate a solution. Currently, I have think of 1. keeping the prev saved.

```
    subl $4, %esp # reserve space to put in the prev pointer
    movl %ebx, -4(%ebp) # store current pointer into prev pointer 
    movl NEXT(%ebx), %ebx # walk down the list
```

and then later on

```
    movl -4(%ebp), %edx # putting the prev pointer into edx
    pushl (%edx) # two pushes to give parameters for func call
    pushl (%ebx)
    call remove_func
```

and in the remove function

```
    movl 12(%ebp), %edx # store prev pointer to edx
    movl 8(%ebp), %ebx # store current pointer aka node to be deleted at ebx
    movl NEXT(%ebx), %eax # temporarily store curr->next to eax
    movl %eax, NEXT(%edx) # prev->next=eax
    movl $0, (%ebx) # curr=NULL
    pushl %ebx # pushes params for func call
    call free_node
```

You have the general idea what this is I am trying to do here. Essentially pushing the prev pointer onto a stack when you are in the process of walking down the list using NEXT. However, with this implementation I am still not certain if it will work or not since I don't know if it can go recursively towards the top or would it stop dead in the first remove. My second way is to just store the prev pointer in a register without pushing onto a stack. Say %edi

```
    movl %ebx,%edi
    movl NEXT(%ebx), %ebx
    call remove_func
```

Thank you for your help. Sorry for the long question. 
EDIT: The list need to be removed in reverse order. It is the classic missile command game I am trying to implement.

Comment: Do you have to delete them in reverse order (from tail to head)?  Or can you just set the head to NULL and then walk through the chain of nodes that you chopped off, freeing them one by one?  If you can't do that, then either a recursive implementation would work, and so would simply pushing node addresses onto the stack while traversing.  (Use a counter to keep track of how many to pop off on the way back when you're deleting.)

Comment: Hmm, if you just need to free them all in reverse order, it might be possible to reverse the list in-place, using only a fixed amount of temporary storage (i.e. a couple registers).  Load the NEXT pointer from a node, then store the address of the previous node.  (You'd want to set HEAD=NULL=0 before doing this, because it leaves the list in a broken state for any other readers).

Comment: **Anyway, it's not clear what your question is.  IDK what you think might not work, or what you think might go wrong.**  As usual, figure out your algorithm in C or pseudocode, then implement in assembly.  IDK why your remove function takes two args, or why it stores anything into memory it's about to free.  It's pretty hard to follow your messy code with no comments, esp. since it keeps storing to the stack and reloading instead of just keeping stuff in registers.

Comment: I need to remove the list in reverse order. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you're having trouble with, but I had an interesting idea for implementing this that takes advantage of the call stack as a stack data structure while traversing forwards, and uses it for arg-passing on the way back without having to copy anything anywhere.

Assumptions: you don't need to modify the list nodes while freeing them.  This is a free-everything function, so we can just set HEAD=NULL so any other users of the linked list (e.g. in signal handlers or other threads) will see it as empty while we're still working through the nodes freeing them.

```
# gas AT&T syntax, x86 32-bit, SysV calling convention
# untested
.globl list_free
list_free:       # void list_free(struct node **phead)
    mov    4(%esp), %eax     # phead:   node**
    mov    (%eax), %edx      # p=head:  node*  (points to the first node)
    # p (pointer to old head) in %edx
    test   %edx,%edx            # check that head wasn't NULL to start
    jz     .Llist_was_empty     # free(NULL) is safe, but we would also try to dereference

    xor    %ecx,%ecx         # count = 0
    mov    %ecx, (%eax)      # *phead=NULL   (chop the list off at the head)

# loop over the list, pushing the address of each node on the stack
.Lforward_loop               # do {
    push   %edx              #  push p
    mov    NEXT(%edx), %edx  #  p=p->next
    inc    %ecx              #  count++
    test   %edx,%edx
    jnz   .Lforward_loop     # } while(p)

# walk back up the stack, using each pointer as an arg to free()
.Lbackward_loop              # do {
    call   free              #   free takes one arg, which is already on the stack
    add    $4, %esp          #   or just pop %edx, which will run faster on Intel CPUs: doesn't force a stack-sync uop
    dec    %ecx              # } while(--count);
    jnz    .Lbackward_loop

.Llist_was_empty:
    ret
```

I intentionally didn't "keep it simple" or anything, because IDK what kind of help you actually need.  I basically wrote this for my own amusement after thinking about your question.  The fewer instructions there are, the less there is to understand. :)

I only needed three registers, so I didn't have to save/restore any.  And I didn't need any locals, so I didn't make a stack frame with ebp either.

---

In 64-bit code (AMD64 SysV calling convention, where first arg goes in %rdi), the backwards loop would be:

```
.Lbackward_loop              # do {
    pop    %rdi
    call   free              #   free(p)
    dec    %ecx              # } while(--count);
    jnz    .Lbackward_loop
```

Comment: Simply marvelous. Thanks for the elegant solution.